# Bitcoin Core switch to release version?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Running on Ubuntu 18.04, I have built Bitcoin Core from source, but the version is 0.18.99, and I would like to be running 0.18.0. I checked out v0.18.0, and went through the build steps again, yet it is still running 0.18.99.

What do I need to do to run 0.18.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the daemon wasn't removed from your system, since it doesn't live in the Bitcoin directory where the blockchain data, wallet, etc is stored.

So you'll need to find where the daemon installed on your system. Try checking `/usr/local/bin` to see if `bitcoind` is there. Delete it, checkout the version you'd like, and then rebuild. You should then be running the proper versoin.

Answer (score 0):

Start by stopping your running version of bitcoin core if you have one

$ su - bitcoin

$ bitcoin-cli stop

Bitcoin server stopping

then install the last version

$ git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git

$ cd bitcoin

$ git checkout v0.18.0

then compile it

$ ./autogen.sh

$ ./configure

$ make -j $(nproc)

Now you can start it

$ bitcoind --version

Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.18.0

$ bitcoind -daemon

Bitcoin server starting

Comment: Instead of cloning I simply pulled from the repository, checked out v0.18.0, and built, but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: doing all the step I give you, should do the work, do you have an error message ?

Comment: No error messages. `$bitcoind —version` gives me Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.18.99.0-e14cd04ab. `$git show` gives me commit 2472733... (HEAD, tag: v0.18.0)

Comment: You should be able to clone then checkout it again

Comment: Removed the bitcoin directory, cloned, built, and still no change. The only difference on my end is that I am setting the flags for `./configure —disable-wallet —without-gui`

Comment: Be careful not to remove wallet.dat in ~/.bitcoin/ if you have not keep your private key, I am not sure about your problem, I guess you could also simply download the last version if you dont mind download the sync again

Comment: I don’t use the wallet, so no worries there, but I’m trying to avoid another sync. Not really a big deal I guess. I don’t use the node for much, but a little frustrating that I can’t simply change versions to an official release.

Comment: I think you could save the sync just move it from the directory, more information here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory